# Linux DBus communication

Tags: linux, ipc, dbus

In Linux D-Bus:

1. What prevents a process A from directly talking to a process B ? Why does a method call message have to go through the bus daemon process ?
2. Why does `<policy>` section in the daemon's config file have an option to allow / deny owning a bus name ?
3. If a process can use matching rules to potentially monitor any message passing through the bus daemon process, can two communicating processes express any restriction in any way such that no other process can observe their traffic ?
4. Why is it said in [documentation](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html#bus-names) that a given bus name will always refer the same application ? - Will this be true after machine reboots ?

For 1: My current understanding is that for processes A and B to talk to each other, both must register a bus name with the bus daemon. So is the only thing preventing A from talking to B is that it may know B's bus name and not be able to locate it on the machine ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a "Question and Answer" site. Note that both "Question" and "Answer" are singular. This is not a "Here is my long list of questions. Answer them." site. It looks like you're not new here - do you need a review of the [help] as a refresher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - nothing. It's just much simpler to use bus ( both services and clients are tcp clients, not servers, easier to configure, manage names etc etc)

2 - to make sure that service behind the name is one you trust. Otherwise malicious code might request name and pretend to be that service.

3 - IMO yes ( though not exactly sure )

4 - name <-> connection. One process can own multiple names. Automatic names are not re-assigned to new connections ( if you reconnect it's always new name ) After reboot you can see same names again, but between reboots you can assume no same name assigned to two different connections over time ( = race conditions )

Comment: For 1: does B have to allow that communication some way ?

Comment: yes, you need to start some server in A or B and initiate connection from client. I have example using dbus transport without dbus daemon here - https://github.com/sidorares/node-dbus/tree/master/examples/p2p

Comment: Also for 1: you mention tcp .. isn't D-bus using unix domain sockets underneath ? what does D-bus save (e.g. location ?) for a process that connects to it, so it can reach the process in future ? .. thanks.

Comment: For 3: I think the eavesdrop="true" | "false" in <policy> might be applicable

Comment: Sorry for so many questions .. but D-bus .. the policy is using a MAC philosophy right ? who sets it ?

Comment: usually unix domain sockets for system bus and abstract sockets for session, but can be tcp as well

Comment: see transport documentation here - http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#transports